# image change by using ng if in angular js

Tags: angularjs

i have a image on click of that image it display a overlay containing a text area and a button to add a comment i am using ng-if to control the image for that text area and button i am showing add image if no comment has been added yet and if comment has been added the and image for edit every thing is working fine but when i enter text in that text it immediately changes the image to edit image by angular binding in html in ng-if. I dont want my image changed to edit because user can click on cross sign and dont add the comment.

html:

```
ng-if="contract.tme_comments == '' || contract.tme_comments == null"
ng-click="commentType($event)" ng-src="img/add.png"
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment so putting the suggestion here.

Have two variables for the comment. Before the overlay opens, initialize the duplicate with the value of original and have your ng-if based off the duplicate variable. Original bounded to the comment element and duplicate is updated when the comment is actually posted.

Alternatively, you can also use ng-bind for the comment and update it when the user submits.